# explode string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the following result through ajax.

```
row=Shimla|1|http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/
```

I wanna http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/ from it. I have used find and split function but it is not working . please let me know how I can get it?

```
var result=$(row).split('|');
    alert(result);
```

chrome showing the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Shimla|1|http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/
```

Comment: the `split('|')` will create 3 strings inside zero-index based array `results`, in which the url you want is the 3rd, so you wanna do `alert(result[2])`

Comment: Most answers mention `$(row).val().split('|')`...But the fact is that functions such as `$(row).val()` or `$(row).text()` are applicable for DOM elements only. This is a variable that as you indicated is coming from an AJAX response. There's absolutely no need to use jQuery for this since it's just string manipulation already available through vanilla JavaScript. Just do `row.split('|')[2]` as indicated by TJ

Comment: The problem isn't the `split` method. The sytax error is given by the fact that OP didn't put quotes around string. I wonder why nobody mentioned it

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will create an array. So you need to access the third element in your case..

[(*arrays are 0-indexed*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements) You need to access `result[2]` to get the url

```
var result = $(row).text().split('|');
alert( result[2] );
```

---

You do not give us enough information to know what `row` is, exactly.. So depending on how you acquire the variable `row` you might need to do one of the following.

- if `row` is a string then `row.split('|');`
- if it is a DOM element then `$(row).text().split('|');`
- if it is an `input` element then `$(row).val().split('|');`

Comment: Jan, just updated answer.. but you will need to tell us where you got `row` from..

Comment: I don't know what is `row` but I do know that `$(...)` is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 11):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method an array . You can access the individual values by using an index.

```
var result = $(row).val().split('|')[2]
alert(result);
```

**OR**

```
var result = $(row).val().split('|');
alert(result[2]);
```

If it's **input element** then you need to use `$(row).val()` to get the value..

Otherwise you would need to use `$(row).text()` or `$(row).html()`

Comment: note that `$(...)` is a jQuery object. JQuery doesn't have the `split` method.

Answer (score 8):

The split function separates each part of text with the separator you provide, and you provided "|". So the result would be an array containing "Shimla", "1" and "http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/". You could manipulate that to get the third one, "http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/", and here's an example:

```
var str="Shimla|1|http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/";
var n = str.split('|');
alert(n[2]);
```

As mentioned in other answers, this code would differ depending on if it was a string ($(str).split('|');), a textbox input ($(str).val().split('|');), or a DOM element ($(str).text().split('|');).

You could also just use plain JavaScript to get all the stuff after 9 characters, which would be "http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/". Here's an example:

```
var str="Shimla|1|http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/";
var n=str.substr(9);
alert(n);
```

Comment: you first version will not work.. if the text is not convertible to html (*needs tags to be*) the jquery will treat it as a selector and return an empty object. So `.text()` on it will return an empty string.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli It depends. 
    if its a string then its split('|');
    if it is a DOM element then text().split('|');
    if it is an input element then val().split('|');

Comment: Yes, but in your first example you set `str` to be a simple string, and then you did `$(str).text()` which would return `""`. Now you removed `.text()` but you left the `$(str)` which would return an empty jquery obejct.. In you first example it should be `str.split('|')`

Answer (score 4):

What is row?

Either of these could be correct.

1) I assume that you capture your ajax response in a javascript variable 'row'. If that is the case, this would hold true.

```
var result=row.split('|');
    alert(result[2]);
```

otherwise

2) Use this where `$(row)` is a `jQuery` object.

```
var result=$(row).val().split('|');
    alert(result[2]);
```

[As mentioned in the other answer, you may have to use `$(row).val()` or `$(row).text()` or `$(row).html()` etc. depending on what $(row) is.]

Answer (score 2):

if your input's id is following

```
<input type='text'  id='kg_row1' >
```

then you can get explode/split the above with the following function of split in jquery

```
  var kg_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var getvalues =kg_id.split("_");
  var id = getvalues[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
var data = 'allow~5'; 
var result=data.split('~');
```

**RESULT**

```
alert(result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a couple jQuery plugin functions to perform this task.

I added a chaining example to show how easy you can transform a string between subsequent calls. This adds a little overhead, but showcases how to perform function chaining for better readability.

```js
(function($) {
  $.sliceAfterIndex = function(str, index) {
    return str.slice(index);
  };
  $.sliceAfter = function(str, substr) {
    return $.sliceAfterIndex(str, str.indexOf(substr) + substr.length);
  };
  $.tokenAt = function(str, delimiter, index) {
    return str.split(delimiter)[index];
  };
  $.strChain = function(str) {
    return {
      __str: str,
      sliceAfterIndex: function(index) {
        this.__str = $.sliceAfterIndex(this.__str, index); return this;
      },
      sliceAfter: function(substr) {
        this.__str = $.sliceAfter(this.__str, substr); return this;
      },
      tokenAt: function(delimiter, index) {
        this.__str = $.tokenAt(this.__str, delimiter, index); return this;
      },
      value: function(delimiter, index) {
        return this.__str;
      }
    };
  };
})(jQuery);

var res = 'row=Shimla|1|http://vinspro.org/travel/ind/';
// Nesting (inside-out)
console.log($.tokenAt($.sliceAfter(res, 'row='), '|', 2));
// Chaining (ltr)
console.log($.strChain(res).sliceAfter('row=').tokenAt('|', 2).value());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```